# jQuery Pagination from getJSON Results (no plugin)

Tags: jquery, json, pagination, getjson

Anyone able to help me with the following:

The below code is a shortened version of my script, which works and displays loads of results. However i want to do some kind of pagination for it and not sure where to start with this: example: show 10 results with next link... click n ext shows next 10 and then prev link etc....

Hoping someone can help me with this

```
$.getJSON(Url).done(function(data) {
  // Console log the returned data (I used for testing to quickly know what data i wanted to display later)

  // Loop through the results
  $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, data) {
    $(".results").append($("<a>").attr("href", PhotoUrl).attr("target", "_blank").append($("<img>").attr("src", ThumbUrl)));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

usually you use a LIMIT Clause in the query and save the START and END values in your script. Then you just call the query with the parameters for the LIMIT Clause when the user clicks the next or previous button.

Comment: Im not getting it from a database, its coming from an API which in this case is Flickr's